# Memory allocation in a Java loop

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-optimization, jit

In a java loop like this:

```java
for (File f : files) {
    String s = f.getName();
}
```

Is it possible to make any claim about the relative locations in memory that will be allotted for `String s` in each iteration of the loop?

Does the compiler know that we will be allocating space for a `String s` repeatedly? If yes, does it allocate some fixed space for it or make other relevant optimisations with this knowledge?

Comment: Well, `String s = ...` is just a reference to the string and the strings themselves probably already have been allocated when creating `files`.

Comment: As for the jit compiler: since it is part of the JVM that would probably depend on which JVM you're using (there are multiple different JVM implementations).

Comment: You need to differ between memory for the variable and memory for the (String) object. See this question (and the link under the question there) for further information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996026/memory-allocation-of-a-variable-in-java